# Elasticsearch boosting not working on mulit match

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Elasticsearch multi match is not boosting fields, here is the code.

```
{
    "size": 15,
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "shoes",
                    "fields": ["category^3", "brand^2", "title^1", "description"],
                    "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [],
                    "should": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally what i want is that if someone searches for the keyword shoes, he should get relevent result. In this case it should see whether there is a category for shoes, this should have a boost of 3. Then it should look whether there is any brand that has the keyword "shoes" in it, this should have a boost of 2. Then it should look in the title and description.

So if a product has all of the above criteria then it should show have the highest boost.

**Edit:** Here is my mapping.

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "products": {
            "properties": {
                "variations": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Well I have not defined the types for the rest of the field. I thought of keeping it the default. Secondly I am not interested in querying the nested fields. because these usually include variations of the products e.g color, size etc. Here is a sample document.

```
{
    "title": "100% Cotton Unstitched Suit For Men",
    "slug": "100-cotton-unstitched-suit-for-men",
    "price": 200,
    "sale_price": 0,
    "vendor_id": 32,
    "featured": 0,
    "viewed": 20,
    "stock": 4,
    "sku": "XXX-B",
    "rating": 0,
    "active": 1,
    "vendor_name": "house_of_suits",
    "brand": "armani",
    "category": [
        "men_fashion",
        "traditional_clothing",
        "unstitched_fabric"
    ],
    "image": "imagename.jpg",
    "variations": [
        {
            "variation_id": "34",
            "stock": 5,
            "price": 200,
            "variation_image": "",
            "sku": "XXX-C",
            "size": "m",
            "color": "red"
        },
        {
            "variation_id": "35",
            "stock": 5,
            "price": 200,
            "variation_image": "",
            "sku": "XXX-D",
            "size": "l",
            "color": "red"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Boost is a factor no an order of "looking". Please give an example with documents (and try ^300 ^200 ^100 instead of ^3 ^2 ^1)

Comment: I have tried your recommendation by adding ^300 ^200 ^100 but there is no effect at all on the scoring.

Comment: Can you please print the full document mapping so that we can see the fields and datatypes for those fields.  Matching queries are meant to run on analyzed fields but I see that your variations nested object is not analyzed.

Comment: @zachdb86 i have updated by answer

Comment: Thanks for posting sample document.  I see that the fields that you want to search are not nested.  I have updated the answer to reflect that.  Also, maybe this is an oversight, but I see that description is missing.  Please trying running explain with the updated query

Answer (score 1):

The filtered query is deprecated and should be replaced with a bool containing at least a must clause and a filter clause.  Also, your field boosting is correct, however, the multi_match scores differently based on the type you define.  The default type, best_fields, uses the _score from the best field.  In the example below, The example below uses the most_fields type, which combines the score from each field, and should accomplish what you want.  I would check out [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) page to learn more about the different types.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "shoes",
            "fields": ["category^3", "brand^2", "title^1", "description"],
            "type": "most_fields"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {

      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks zachdb . I have followed your instructions but for some reason i am still not getting a boost on these fields. Secondly the highest score for relevance is less than 1. But more than one field have the query in it. Do you think it might have to do something with the mapping. I have edited my answer and included my map

Comment: In this query ths boost-Factor is possible to small to see the difference. How do you know, that you getting no boost?

Comment: Can you please run explain on this query and paste the output.

Comment: @zachdb86 I have tried the above query but it gets 0 hits